# Avoid refresh of Repeater after Click in LinkButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, asprepeater

I have a repeater with a LinkButton inside. A click raises an event that passes the repeater ID as a CommandArgument and displays detailed Information regarding that ID in a GridView. How can I avoid that the click causes the page to reload the Repeater?

I wrapped the Repeater in a UpdatePanel, with the result that exactly the contrary is happening: The GridView is not loaded, while the repeater is.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" ScrollBars="Vertical" Height="600px">
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="RepeaterKalendar">
            <ItemTemplate>  
                <asp:label ID="Month_lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Month") %>'/>
                <asp:label ID="Pretag_lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PRETAG") %>'/>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="ButtonSelect" runat="server" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("date") %>' Text='<%# Bind("TAG") %>' OnClick="GetDetails"/> 
                <asp:label ID="Posttag_lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("POSTTAG") %>'/>
                <asp:label ID="Monthend_lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MonthEnd") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        </asp:Panel>
     </ContentTemplate>
     <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonSelect" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I've added the Panel tag  -which I originally skipped, thinking it would just distract- as I found out that the Repeater actually is NOT reloading. It seems that the scrolling position inside the panel is lost after the LinkButton Click, as it jumps to it's starting position. I interpreted this behavior as the result of the Repeater being rebound.

Any comment on the lost of the scrolling position inside the panel?

Comment: Add the `GridView' to the contentTemplate of the UpdatePanel

Comment: You have to wrap the databinding of the Repeater inside an `IsPostBack` check.

Comment: if the page is reloading then it means that ajax updatepanel is not working correctly. try to put a button in the contenttemplate with runat="server" tag and see if that also reloads the page. also check if you have <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager> defined above the update panel ??

Comment: I was probably wrong: The UpdatePanel seems to work, BUT what I interpreted as a reload of the Repeater was actually the fact that after the post the scrolling position of the repeater inside a Panel is reset to the starting position. I use the repeater to display a Calendar inside a scrollable Panel. So it's the Scroll Position that is lost, not the Repeater that is rebound.